# pressKey Enter on contenteditable in Safari

Tags: safari, automated-tests, chatbot, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to use TestCafe to test a chatbot which uses a `contenteditable` div as the user-input. Have actually succeeded with Chrome and Firefox to press `enter` and pass the tests, but have not been able to get Safari to press `enter`. I realize that `contenteditable` does not support `pressKey("enter")` but I'm wondering why it works for both Chrome and Firefox and not Safari, and whether I can get it to work for Safari?

```
test("Able to send a message on enter keypress", async t => {
  await t
    .typeText(chatbot.userReply, "hi")
    .pressKey("enter")
    .expect(chatbot.transcriptMessages.find("li").withText("hi").count).eql(1)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to say why this does not work in Safari without researching a working sample showing the problem. As far as I understand from your description, your contenteditable element has the `keypress` event handler, which sends a message on the `enter` press. I've prepared a sample project to demonstrate this approach, and it all operates correctly both Safari and Chrome:

Test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black;">test</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('editor').addEventListener('keypress', function() { alert('test') })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Test code:

```
fixture `test`
    .page `../pages/index.html`;

test(`test`, async t => {
    await t.click('#editor');
    await t.pressKey('enter');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I have an event handler listening to `keydown` for the `enter` press. I forgot to mention that this is all in an iframe, could that be one of the reasons?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you have a sample project that demonstrates the issue, you can create a ticket on github https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md

Answer (score 1):

In a comment on this page you mentioned that this is in an iframe so you will need to do:

```
await t.switchToIframe(iframeSelector);
```

When switching back you can do:

```
await t.switchToMainWindow();
```